# laravel break parameter name in route

Tags: laravel

after defining a simple below route into `web.php`:

```php
Route::prefix('{language}')->middleware(['setLanguage'])->group(function () {
    Route::prefix('panel')->group(function () {
        Route::prefix('contactusmodule')->group(function () {
            Route::resource('contactUs', 'ContactUsController')->names('contactUs');
        });
    });
});
```

i try to get route name by this code:

```php
request()->route()->parameters()
```

here my route parameters are: `language` and `contactUs` and when i locate this url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/panel/contactusmodule/contactUs/3/edit
```

with this route as:

```php
route('contactUs.edit',[app()->getLocale(),$contact->id])
```

i should get `language` and `contactUs`, but i get this array:

```php
array:2 [
  "language" => "en"
  "contactU" => "3"
]
```

as you can see in this output problem is `contactU` which that should be `contactUs`

output of dumping route:

```php
dd(request()->route()->getName(),request()->route()->parameters());


//output:

"contactUs.edit"

array:2 [▼
  "language" => "en"
  "contactU" => "3"
]
```

in our code by default we should get value from `request()->route()->getName()`. laravel route name is limited? how can resolve this problem?

thanks in advance

Comment: `Route::resource` is for resource names, and it automatically converts them to "singular" for the parameter name used, the singular (based on the mechanism that does it) for `contactUs` is `contactU` ... you can disable this for this route definition or define the name of the parameter explicitly if you would like

Comment: @lagbox thanks, how can I disable that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As lagbox says, it's caused by Laravel grammar parameterize that automatically convert plural route name to singular variable name. Laravel think `contactUs` is plural of `contactU`. If you want to use `contactUs` as param, just override it by adding `->parameters()` method like below:

```
Route::resource('contactUs', 'Cms\Auth\LoginController')->names('contactUs')->parameters(['contactUs' => 'contactUs']);;
```